# Trigger Insert with a SELECT/JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a trigger **INSERT AFTER:** with I inside `SELECT` AND `JOIN`.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `InsertArticle`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `InsertArticle` AFTER INSERT ON `article`

FOR EACH ROW 
  insert into log (LogTime, LogIdNote, LogName, LogType, LogIdUser, logTypeCategory, LogTypeUser, LogUrl) 
    select NEW.ArticleTime, NEW.idArticle, NEW.ArticleName, 1, NEW.ArticleToUserID, NEW.ArticleCategory, u.UsersTypeAccount, ct.URLCategorysubscribetotype
    from users u where u.idUsers = NEW.ArticleToUserID LEFT JOIN categorysubscribetotype ct ON ct.CategoryTypeCategorysubscribetotype = 1;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

When I tried to create trigger, I get **error 1422**.
May be I have a wrong trigger sintax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `InsertArticle`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `InsertArticle` AFTER INSERT ON `article`

FOR EACH ROW 
  insert into log (LogTime, LogIdNote, LogName, LogType, LogIdUser, logTypeCategory, LogTypeUser, LogUrl) 
    select NEW.ArticleTime, NEW.idArticle, NEW.ArticleName, 1 as LogType, NEW.ArticleToUserID, NEW.ArticleCategory, u.UsersTypeAccount, ct.URLCategorysubscribetotype
    from users u  LEFT JOIN categorysubscribetotype ct ON ct.CategoryTypeCategorysubscribetotype = 1 where u.idUsers = NEW.ArticleToUserID;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger. #1422

Comment: May be Mysql does not support?

Comment: you added left join in where condition. it is corrected in my answer check now. @Elhan