# How do I add NEW.[table alias].[table column] MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql

I am not sure how to do this with insert trigger.  I want to add a log which inserts from a "somewhat complex" Select statement with a few Joins so I need table alias.  When I run a test insert I get.  Basically all the columns will need to select NEW.[table alias].[column name] but Only addded SELECT NEW.p.passenger_id, NEW.p.first_name for simplicity

`Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'NEW.p.passenger_id' in 'field list'`

Here is code

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trip_after_insert;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trip_after_insert
    AFTER INSERT ON passenger_schedule
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO trip_purchase_audit 
    (passenger_id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    train_id,
    sequence,
    car_number,
    from_station_id,
    start_station_name,
    to_station_id,
    to_station_name,
    ticket_cost,
    travel_date,
    action_type,
    action_date)
SELECT NEW.p.passenger_id, NEW.p.first_name, p.last_name, ps.train_id, ps.sequence, car_number,
ts.station_start_id, s1.station_name as station_start, ts.station_end_id, s2.station_name as station_end, 
ps.ticket_cost, ps.travel_date, 'TICKET PURCHASE', NOW()
FROM passenger_schedule ps 
    JOIN passengers p ON ps.passenger_id = p.passenger_id
    JOIN train_schedule ts ON ps.train_id = ts.train_id
                          AND ps.sequence = ts.sequence
                          AND ps.ticket_cost = ts.ticket_cost
    RIGHT JOIN stations s1 ON ts.station_start_id = s1.station_id
    RIGHT JOIN stations s2 ON ts.station_end_id = s2.station_id;
END//

INSERT INTO passenger_schedule 
VALUES 
(5007, 4, 2, 4, 8, '2019-01-21'),
(5008, 2, 1, 1, 9, '2019-01-21');
```

Comment: Simply `SELECT p.passenger_id, p.first_name`  should work just fine `NEW` should be used when you need the table within the `AFTER INSERT ON passenger_schedule` SQL so `NEW` directs to that.

Comment: correct I need it to be NEW.  I only want to insert in the audit table the new entries from the complex select clause

Comment: Not sure what you mean or want.. i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide text formatted data and text formatted results.

Comment: i see sorry, i need to do something like this but I think I have it,  i need to create a primary key for trip id on the passenger schedule table and use a where clause https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461272/trigger-insert-with-a-select-join

Comment: The trigger is on the `passenger_schedule` table. `NEW.{field}` the field has to be a member of the `passenger_schedule` table. What is the `SHOW CREATE TABLE passenger_schedule`?

Comment: yup i just noticed that from the link where they added that to the answer in the link they added `where u.idUsers = NEW.ArticleToUserID` and correct it would be the `NEW.{field}` on passenger_schedule.  Thanks!